# What server does Thunderbird query when checking for program updates?

Tags: thunderbird

I can find absolutely no information about this.  I assume that thunderbird (the email application program) has some built-in host names that are contacted when the program checks for updates.  Are these host-names known?  Perhaps they are visible in the about:configuration settings menu?  Or does thunderbird use hard-coded IP addresses for this?

There have been pages and pages written about how to disable thunderbird update checking (on windoze platforms at least) but none so far have mentioned adding HOSTS file entries to render the update server unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely well documented code is available for Thunderbird. I'm not sure why you haven't found the information.  A Google Search for ["thunderbird app update url"](https://www.google.com/search?q=thunderbird%20app%20update) returns [Mozilla Software Updates](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Checking_For_Updates) as the first result.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

##### Software Updates from Mozilla

Mozilla Software Updates are generated using the following format for all Mozilla products including Thunderbird

| https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/6/%PRODUCT%/%VERSION%/%BUILD_ID%/%BUILD_TARGET%/%LOCALE%/%CHANNEL%/%OS_VERSION%/%SYSTEM_CAPABILITIES%/%DISTRIBUTION%/%DISTRIBUTION_VERSION%/update.xml |
| --- |
| '6' is the schema version |
| PRODUCT: App name (e.g., 'Firefox') |
| VERSION: App version (e.g. '3.0a8pre') |
| BUILD_ID: Build ID (e.g., '2007083015') |
| BUILD_TARGET: Build target (e.g., 'Darwin_x86-gcc3') |
| LOCALE: App locale (e.g., 'en-US') |
| CHANNEL: AUS channel (e.g., 'default') |
| OS_VERSION: Operating System version (e.g., 'Darwin%208.10.1') |
| DISTRIBUTION: Name of customized distribution, if any (e.g., 'testpartner') |
| DISTRIBUTION_VERSION: Version of the customized distribution (e.g., '1.0) |

> *none so far have mentioned adding HOSTS file entries to render the update server unreachable.*

It is probably unnecessary.  Thunderbird code is freely available and largely transparent and the ability to disable auto updates is supported.  Mozilla isn't typically viewed as evil or big brother, and given that their software is free, the impetus to avoid connecting *ever* to their servers (as some worry about doing with other companies when running certain software packages that might become disabled during an update) isn't there.

I expect that disabling auto-updates is the recommended approach over hosts file approaches. Note that disabling the ability to access aus5.mozilla.org will likely disable all Mozilla product and security updates as well (e.g. Firefox) in case that is a concern for you.

##### Mozilla Thunderbird Code

Freely available on Github [mozilla > releases-comm-central](https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central)

> Thunderbird is built on the Mozilla platform, the same base that Firefox is built from. As such the two projects share a lot of code and much of the documentation for one will apply, in many ways, to the other.
>
> The mozilla-central repostitory contains the Firefox codebase and all of the platform code. The comm-central repository is added as a subdirectory "comm/" under mozilla-central. This contains the code for Thunderbird.

Comment: What you claim as the "answer" states that aus2.mozilla.org is the host name that thunderbird checks for updates. But aus2.mozilla.org does not resolve to an IP address. It is an unknown host. Check it yourself with nslookup.

Comment: Updated answer with new URL.  Be nice, keep in mind I'm giving you my time.

Comment: @PeggySchafer On a no deleted “answer” you replied to me and said, “What you claim as the "answer" states that aus2.mozilla.org is the host name that thunderbird checks for updates. But aus2.mozilla.org does not resolve to an IP address. It is an unknown host. Check it yourself with nslookup.” I think you missed the core point of my comment and why that “answer” was deleted: Your whole “answer” was basically a comment. Good to see it was posted here, but please do not post comments as answers.

Comment: The Mozilla documentation seems to be outdated or the server name is just an example as the major part of the documentation is about building the URL path. E.g. [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Checking_For_Updates) the server `aus2.mozilla.org` is mentioned which also does not exist (anymore).